# AngularJS & jQuery - How to find the ID of a child div on a Click event for its parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have code in HTML like:

```
<div id="edit" ng-click="editFunction($scope)">
  <span id="1">
    click1
  </span>
  <span id="2">
    click2
  </span>
  <span id="3">
    click3
  </span>
  <span id="4">
    click4
  </span>
  ....
</div>
```

In controller.js:

```
myDIV.controller('control',function($scope){
   $scope.editFunction($event){
    alert($event.target.id);
   }
});
```

When a user clicks on the div tag, he should click on any of the span tags. Using the code we are able to get the div id.

However, I need to know which span is clicked. Meaning, the ID of that span.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. You say you get the id which is from the target which is a `<span>` . So it seems the code does what you are asking already

Comment: I believe you must pass $event instead of $scope in your callback function

Comment: My intension is when I click in div tag, it will be clicked on any of the span tags as all span tags are in div tag. So when I click on div, I am getting div ID. But I want ID of SPAN, which is being clicked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By sending $index, you get the number of the element in the current repeat.

So instead of trying to send an event, and then understand from that what span was clicked, just use the tools that angular gives you out of the box.

> HTML

```
<div id="edit">
    <span ng-repeat="click in clicks" ng-click="editFunction($index)">
        {{ click }}
    </span>
</div>
```

> And then in your controller:

```
myDIV.controller('control',function($scope){

    $scope.clicks = [1, 2, 3, 4]; // Fill the array with real data.

    $scope.editFunction(index){
        alert(index);
    }
});
```

Comment: But we have the event for div tag but not span tag

Comment: @ramprakashseepana Because this is angular you don't need any event, the ng-click attribute makes sure that when you click it goes to the relevant function, and since you send it the index, it knows what index to change. I would suggest you brush up a little on angular, and then it will easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

U can use like this

```
 <div id="edit" ng-click="editFunction($event)">
 element.target.attributes.id.value
```